# returning JSON file as JSONArray in Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am developing a Spring Boot application in which I have a JSON properties file:

```
{
    data: [
        {"firstWebServiceUrl":"http://localhost:8080/firstUrl/"},
        {"secondWebServiceUrl":"http://localhost:8080/secondUrl/"},
    ]
}
```

I have created a controller to read and return this file as `org.json.JSONArray` object:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Test")
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getJsonProperties", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public JSONArray getJsonProperties() {
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/static/configs/properties.json");
        InputStream resourceAsStream;
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        JSONArray jsonArray = null;
        String resourceAsString = null;
        try {
            resourceAsStream = resource.getInputStream();
            byte[] resourceInBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(resourceAsStream);
            resourceAsString = new String(resourceInBytes);
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(resourceAsString);          
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
            System.out.println("json array object is " + jsonArray);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonArray;
    }

}
```

When i call this method I see the output in the console (thanks to sysout):

```
json array object is [{"firstWebServiceUrl":"http://localhost:8080/firstUrl/"},{"secondWebServiceUrl":"http://localhost:8080/secondUrl/"}]
```

as expected. However when I call this method from the browser by entering the url: `http://localhost:8090/Test/getJsonProperties` I get the output:

```
{"empty":false}
```

instead of the contents. How can I return the contents?

Comment: have you tried debugging this and see what jsonArray holds in real time? I think you might be swallowing an exception because you catch everything in your catch clause. try seeing when happens without the try clause.

Comment: @Xeo28 jsonArray holds the value as stated in the question. I just tried without catching but i don't see any exception

Comment: How should Spring Boot know how to serialize JSONArray?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli good point, Spring Boot includes jackson and I can see it in my dependency hierarchy, but clearly it is not working as expected. Could you suggest a way to serialize my JSONArray please? Using POJO is not an option as there are hundreds of arrays in the file.

Comment: I added an answer. Simply call toString on JSONArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return a String instead of JSONArray because there is no default converter that could serialize a JSONArray into a JSON string:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Test")
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getJsonProperties", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String getJsonProperties() {
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/static/configs/properties.json");
        InputStream resourceAsStream;
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        JSONArray jsonArray = null;
        String resourceAsString = null;
        try {
            resourceAsStream = resource.getInputStream();
            byte[] resourceInBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(resourceAsStream);
            resourceAsString = new String(resourceInBytes);
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(resourceAsString);          
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
            System.out.println("json array object is " + jsonArray);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonArray != null ? jsonArray.toString() : "[]";
    }

}
```

Comment: jsonArray.toString() does not compile.

Comment: Have you copied my code or just added the last line? The method must return String